# Rails build relation with many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've got two models:

```
Property
belongs_to :portfolios

Portfolio
has_many :properties
```

I'll need a setup costs record for each property in the portfolio. These will exist in relation to the portfolio setup costs.

How to setup such thing? is this a many-to-many relation?

Comment: If I understand it correctly there would be a setup cost for each portfolio and you need to somehow add that portfolio setup cost on each property of the portfolio. The setup cost will be separate for each property or the same for all?

Comment: @DeepeshKakani each portfolio will have separate setup costs and each property will have separate setup costs

Comment: Yes but suppose _Portfolio A_ has _Property X_ and _Property Y_ so the portfolio setup cost for X and Y would be the same right? Like in this case you can keep that on the portfolio itself?

Comment: @DeepeshKakani nope, it could be something else entirely

Comment: Okay so in that case you can add some columns on the join table similar to what answer has been given by Danish, you can add the relevant columns on PropertyPortfolioLink, would that work for you?

Comment: @DeepeshKakani Isn't it so that if I add something to this join_table I have to have some kind of polymorphic relation? because some of the data will be for the whole portfolio and some will be for individual property

Comment: So if the data is for the whole portfolio why not keep it in the portfolio record itself? Also, I think you are not clear on the association (has_many :through), the join table record will belong to the property and portfolio both so the data you would keep there could belong to any record.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular is `Mono-transitive Association`, you can do this:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :property_portfolio_links
  has_many :portfolios, through: :property_portfolio_links
end

# in between
class PropertyPortfolioLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :portfolio
end

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :property_portfolio_links
  has_many :properties, through: :property_portfolio_links
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question and the comments I understand that you want to have setup_costs for both Portfolio and Property. You don't need a many to many relationship for that. You can add 'setup_costs' column in both tables i.e. Property and Portfolio.

Then later on if you need the total setup costs for a Portfolio including its properties' setup_costs you can do this:

```
total_setup_costs = @portfolio.setup_cost + @portfolio.properties.pluck(:setup_costs).inject(:+)
```

set the default value of the columns 'setup_costs' as 0 while creating them